# Multiple file upload instances on a form

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

How can I use multiple file upload instances on a single form? I want to define a specific file name for each upload so that I use that name at server side to get the data. For example like

```
 <div id="Front-View"><file name="front_view"/></div>
 <div id="Angeled-View"><file name="angeled_view"/></div>  
 <div id="other-View"><file name="other_view"/></div>    
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Front-View').fineUploader({
        request: {
          endpoint: '/upload.do'
        }
    });
    $('#Angeled-View').fineUploader({
        request: {
          endpoint: '/upload.do'
        }
    });
    $('#other-View').fineUploader({
        request: {
          endpoint: '/upload.do'
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: It's not clear why you are using multiple instances, nor is it clear what form you are referring to.  Also,  I'm a bit confused about your mention of "a specific file name".  Can you please provide some more information regarding your specific situation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go with the assumption that you simply want to differentiate between your 3 different Fine Uploader instances when handling files server-side.  With that in mind, you have two options.

## Option 1: Variable URI path

Simply specify a specific endpoint for each uploader instance.  Your server may or may not be setup to handle this currently.

## Option 2: Variable parameter

You can ask Fine Uploader to send a specific parameter with each file it uploads.  You can ensure this parameter identifies the uploader, in your case.  Note that I have simplified your code a bit, and left off the initial HTML:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Front-View, #Angled-View, #other-View').each(function() {
        $(this).fineUploader({
            request: {
                endpoint: '/upload.do', 
                params: {
                    uploaderId: this.id
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The above code will send a parameter, `uploaderId`, along with each file.  The parameter's value will match the ID of the uploader's associated `<div>`.